# Is checkout necessary to work on branch

Tags: bitbucket

I have created a repository in Bitbucket and have added some code in the master branch. Then I created a branch `dev` and I intend to work on `dev` branch and sync it with master when required.

To work on dev, do I need to run `git fetch && git checkout dev` or could I simply change my local code (eg change a file or add a file) and push it on `dev` using following commands?

```
git remote add origin https://username@your.bitbucket.domain:7999/yourproject/repo.git 
git push -u origin dev
```

I am sceptical trying this without guidance as I have faced issues where the branches are no longer in sync!

Comment: I would strongly recommend checking out the branch.  You might get away with it, but I'd suggest it's bad practice.     I'd also suggest you add the `git` tag and possibly remove the `bitbucket` tag, because this is mostly about git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is. When I create a branch in Bitbucket, the branch gets created there but not in my local machine. The local machine still has only master branch. the commands `git fetch && git checkout dev` run on local machine (in project directory) creates `dev` branch in local machine.

```
C:\...\dw-ng2-app>git fetch && git checkout dev
From ssh://bitbucket.org/ManuChadha/angularcli
 * [new branch]      dev        -> origin/dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
```

Any changes I'll do now in local machine will be in `dev` and will be pushed to `dev` in Bitbucket.

So following commands are now applied to local `dev` and `dev` on bit bucket

```
C:\...\dw-ng2-app>git add --all
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

C:\...\dw-ng2-app>git commit -m "added names"
[dev d3749c7] added names
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)

C:\...\dw-ng2-app>git push origin dev
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 482 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for dev:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/ManuChadha/angularcli/pull-requests/new?source=dev&t=1
remote:
To ssh://bitbucket.org/ManuChadha/angularcli.git
   cddddca..d3749c7  dev -> dev
```